# How to identify a terminating pod in kubernetes using java

Tags: java, kubernetes, fabric8

I am using fabric8 to get the status of a kuberenetes pod by the following code.

```
KubernetesHelper.getPodStatusText(pod);
```

I deploy an app within a container and there is a one to one mapping between a container and pod. My requirement is to redeploy the application. So after deleting the pod I check for the status and the method returns a status of "Running" while deleting.

I am unable to identify that the pod has been deleted since the newly deployed app also return a status of "Running". Are there any other variables of a pod that can be used to identify a healthy pod vs a terminating pod.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this is to perform a rolling upgrade. This will ensure that your deployed application incurs no downtime (new pods are started before old pods are stopped). One caveat is that you must be using a replication controller or replication set to do so. Most rolling deployments will simply involve just updating the container's image for the new version of software.

You can do this through Java via [fabric8](http://fabric8.io)'s [Kubernetes Java client](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client). [Here](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/blob/a47d2e288599559069481895c8b6fc7cf3fbab3d/kubernetes-examples/src/main/java/io/fabric8/kubernetes/examples/FullExample.java#L147)'s an example:

```
client.replicationControllers()
    .inNamespace("thisisatest")
    .withName("nginx-controller")
    .rolling().updateImage("nginx");
```

You can change any configuration of the replication controller (replicas, environment variables, etc). The call will return when your pods running the new version are `Ready` & the old replication & pods have been stopped & deleted.